# Captcha failed to display

Tags: bug, status-declined, captcha

I just got a failure with the captcha system. Sequence of events:

1. Answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852299/how-to-prevent-values-from-being-converted-to-strings-in-javascript)
2. The OP changed the question such that my previous answer didn't apply, so I deleted that answer
3. Wrote a new answer that answered the new question
4. Got a captcha display with the usual robots picture and the "I'm a human being" button
5. There was **NO** captcha display or box to enter anything
6. Pressing the "I'm a human being" button said I didn't enter the words correctly
7. Tried several times to add a new answer, with the same results as above
8. Gave up and undeleted and edited my previous answer instead, which worked without any captcha required

I'm using Firefox 4 on Windows 7 with [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) installed. (I'm sure that I've successfully used the captcha after installing HTTPS Everywhere several weeks ago.)

Comment: I'm curious whether the upvotes mean "hey I saw that too" or just "good question" :)

Comment: They mean "Hey! I also want a blank captcha!"

Comment: see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2458/captcha-not-showing-input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems [Google nowadays wants](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html) sites to use `www.google.com/recaptcha/api/` rather than `api.recaptcha.net`. The old domain redirects to the new URL, and Google recently stated [it will continue doing so](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/msg/65702e5ec07f8059).

However, Google has recently [stopped HTTPS support](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/57baacc2a067035a/8e88d1199244a778?tvc=2) for the old domain:

> IMPORTANT: changes to reCAPTCHA SSL API (api-secure.recaptcha.net) on April 11
>
> In April, we will begin to turn down the legacy URL for reCAPTCHA's 
>   HTTPS API.  If your site uses reCAPTCHA over SSL, you will need to 
>   make a minor code change before April 11.
>
> [...]
>
> FYI, we are now purposely serving an expired SSL certificate for api-secure.recaptcha.net. This is expected behavior.

HTTPS Everywhere rewrites `api.recaptcha.net` to the obsolete `api-secure.recaptcha.net`. This [https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Ld...](https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc) still works with a warning, but apparently fails silently when embedded in another web page.

But the new URL from the documentation, [https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Ld...](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc), is fine for both HTTP and HTTPS. So: though not officially required, maybe the Stack Exchange HTML could be changed to adhere to the current documentation? Without any additional work, that would magically also make add-ons such as HTTPS Everywhere work again.

In the meantime, in HTTPS Everywhere: how about an exception for `api.recaptcha.net`, or some rewrite to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api` for that domain?

Comment: That's for the analysis! There's a recent update to HTTPS Everywhere that appears to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

We're using a [ReCaptcha](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/) supplied library, and it's still* emitting the old API paths.

Frankly, if Google doesn't think its worth fixing I don't.  Furthermore, its only a problem because HTTPS Everywhere is re-writing to the (now) incorrect url.

```
<rule to="https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/" from="^http://api\.recaptcha\.net/"/>
```

in \chrome\content\rules\GoogleAPIs.xml.

<sub>*We were on an older library version, so I've kicked us up to the latest.  Both link in the same resources.</sub>

Comment: It turns out there's an update to HTTPS Everywhere that fixes this redirect. I suggest the question tag be changed to "status-resolved".

Comment: We [can't trust Google](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/7a4839d13ac3dcf5/a51be72cd56c1461?hl=en) any more ;-) *"The plugins we officially support have been updated to use the new URLs by default."* Still then, as HTTPS Everywhere fixes this, I guess it's indeed fine to not change things.

Comment: @Greg, maybe this should be the accepted answer?